# Is there a way to configure a static IP for the LoadBalancer resource in AKS with the Web Application Routing add-on enabled?

Tags: azure, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks

I have successfully configured an AKS cluster and have added the Web Application Routing add-on (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/web-app-routing?tabs=without-osm). The link to the add-on documentation describes the steps to configure access to the DNS zone for automatic A-record management and also an example deployment, service and ingress resource. In my lab setup this works quite well, I am even able to automatically deploy new environments of our in-house developed Django app to this cluster using Gitlab CI.

Now the time has come to move this cluster into production. Because I want to create some static DNS records, I want the ingress resource to use a static public IP address that is not tied into the lifecycle of the AKS cluster. As far as I'm aware, when the add-on is enabled a service of type 'LoadBalancer', name 'nginx' and namespace 'app-routing-system' is created, which allows incoming HTTP traffic to be directed to the proper Services.

The problem is that I do not know how to configure the LoadBalancer-type ingress resource. There is documentation about LoadBalancer annotations that regard Public IP (https://cloud-provider-azure.sigs.k8s.io/topics/loadbalancer/#loadbalancer-annotations) but I'm not sure how to set this property during the enabling of the add-on. There is also no option for adding annotations in the `az aks addon update` CLI method (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cli/azure/aks/addon?view=azure-cli-latest#az-aks-addon-update).